# Problemas con alineación de cajas flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estoy intentando hacer una página web con flexbox y tengo un problema cuando quiero alinear tres cajas con una que hay arriba, así: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs3nm.jpg
[image: Las tres cajas divididas de forma igual con la de arriba]
Para eso he intentado dividir las cajas de abajo con un width: calc (100% / 3), dividiendo el ancho 100 de la caja entre tres para que me alinee las tres cajas, pero no sé porque no me las alinea con la de arriba. A lo mejor no es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Aquí está el código CSS y HTML

```css
        .cont-main {
            width: 100%;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .box-first {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
                .article-pdg {
            padding: 24px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .article-main-first {
            padding: 24px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        /*main*/
        .first-article-main {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction:row;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .amp-img-first {
            width: 65.1%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .amp-text-first {
            width: 34.9%;
            padding-left: 24px;
        }

        
        .amp-text-first {
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .title-main-first {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        
 
        .box-news-cover {
            width: calc(100% / 3);
        }
        .cont-box-news-cover {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
  <main>
      <div class="container">
          
          <div class="cont-main flex">
              
              <div class="box-first flex">
                  
                  <article class="first-article-main article-main-first flex">
                      <div class="amp-img-first">
                         <a href="#">
                          <img alt="A view of the sea"
                          class="amp-main-first-picture"
  src="https://via.placeholder.com/735x302"
  width="735"
  height="302"
  layout="responsive">
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="amp-text-first flex">
                          <span class="category-main"><a href="#">Categoria</a></span>
                          
                          <div class="cont-text-main-first">
                          <h2 class="title-main-first"><a href="#">Título</a></h2>
                          <p class="details-main-first">Subtitulo</p>
                          </div>
                          
                          <span class="date-main-first">Date</span>
                      </div>
                  </article>
                  
                  <div class="cont-box-news-cover flex">
                  <article class="box-news-cover article-pdg">
                      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500

</span>
                  </article>
                                    <article class="box-news-cover article-pdg">
<img src="img/000_1qx5q8-2_5eac526fb484d.jpg" class="img">
                  </article>
                                    <article class="box-news-cover article-pdg">
                      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

</span>
                  </article>
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
              
              <div class="box-secundary"></div>
              
          </div>
          
      </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: Dos secciones de las tres deben dar el ancho de la caja gris y la otra el ancho del texto (categoría, titulo, subtitulo...)

Comment: He dividido los tres en porcentaje con el width calc 100 / 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré dos problemas, el primero es no usas `display: flex` en el contenedor padre, lo otro es el `padding`, q le agregas a la cajas para separarlas (esto le agrega ancho a este)

> 65.1% + (34.9% + 24px) // Esto dara mas del 100% del ancho, lo cual la ultima caja ira hacia abajo

Una solución fácil es usa `calc()`

```css
.cont-main {
            width: 100%;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .box-first {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
                .article-pdg {
            padding: 24px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .article-main-first {
            padding: 24px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        /*main*/
        .first-article-main {
            display: flex; //esto es nuevo
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction:row;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .amp-img-first {
            width: 65.1%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .amp-text-first {
            width: calc(34.9% - 24px) //restando padding;
            padding-left: 24px;
        }

        
        .amp-text-first {
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .title-main-first {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        
 
        .box-news-cover {
            width: calc(100% / 3);
        }
        .cont-box-news-cover {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<main>
      <div class="container">
          
          <div class="cont-main flex">
              
              <div class="box-first flex">
                  
                  <article class="first-article-main article-main-first flex">
                      <div class="amp-img-first">
                         <a href="#">
                          <img alt="A view of the sea"
                          class="amp-main-first-picture"
  src="https://via.placeholder.com/735x302"
  width="735"
  height="302"
  layout="responsive">
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="amp-text-first flex">
                          <span class="category-main"><a href="#">Categoria</a></span>
                          
                          <div class="cont-text-main-first">
                          <h2 class="title-main-first"><a href="#">Título</a></h2>
                          <p class="details-main-first">Subtitulo</p>
                          </div>
                          
                          <span class="date-main-first">Date</span>
                      </div>
                  </article>
                  
                  <div class="cont-box-news-cover flex">
                  <article class="box-news-cover article-pdg">
                      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500

</span>
                  </article>
                                    <article class="box-news-cover article-pdg">
<img src="img/000_1qx5q8-2_5eac526fb484d.jpg" class="img">
                  </article>
                                    <article class="box-news-cover article-pdg">
                      <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

</span>
                  </article>
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
              
              <div class="box-secundary"></div>
              
          </div>
          
      </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: Adicional, te recomiendo usar https://css3generator.com/ para q' te familiarices con flexbox

Comment: Me sirvió de mucho! Muchas gracias y seguiré practicando! Un saludo